# Custom post query error

Tags: query-posts

i have a ~46k rows in my wp_posts. All i want to do is to query the database that meet my queryes and display the resulted posts but my problem is that any query that i`m doing to the database it display only the last 5 entryes that were added. Thats the code:

```
if(isset($_GET["submit"])){

$nume_searchq=$_GET["nume_doc"];
$spec_searchq=$_GET["specializare_doc"];
$instit_searchq=$_GET["spital_doc"];
?>

<hr>
<strong>Rezultatele cautarii:</strong>
</br>

<?php

$query= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_content like '%Alba%' OR LOWER(post_title) LIKE '%$nume_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$spec_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$instit_searchq%' ".$limit, OBJECT);
 $pageposts =get_posts($query);
if($pageposts){
    foreach($pageposts as $post){
                    global $post;
                    setup_postdata($post);
                    echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"> ' . get_the_title() . ' </a></li>';
wp_reset_postdata();
}//end_Foreach
}//end_if
?>
```

I have tried different methods and queryes and still the most recent 5 entryies it display...how can i fix this?
PS: dont bother about the $limit variable because i have a pagination code under this query.
Thanks!

LE: i changed the code a bit and i have results but in my query **i only need posts** and it display absolutely everything that it found in the db, including small pictures, contact form, different pages, different codes, posts etc. Code looks like this for the moment:

```
    <?php 
   switch($_GET['filter1']){


   case "ALL":
        $querystr = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type='post' OR LOWER(post_title) LIKE '%$nume_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$spec_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$instit_searchq%' ";
          break;
       case "AB":
          $querystr = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_content LIKE '%Alba%' AND post_type='post' OR LOWER(post_title) LIKE '%$nume_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$spec_searchq%' OR LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%$instit_searchq%' ";
         break;
    ..... //more case`es }

   $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT); ?>
 <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
 <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
 <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

 <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php //display_rating_result(); ?>
    <div class="entry">
      <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  
    <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php else : ?>
   <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
 <?php endif; 


 }//end_submit 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`get_posts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_posts/) doesn't accept *posts* as input, it only takes argument to query posts. So it's useless and breaking step in your process. It should work if you throw `get_posts()` out.

See [Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) in Codex for extensive writeup on custom queries.

PS your query is **seriously insecure**, you need to be escaping any untrusted inputs.

Comment: Nop, it doesnt work. It display nothing, a blank screen. And from that place i took it and i changed it a bit.

Comment: @Frapping please update your question with new code if you are trying something different

Comment: Edited, check it out.